# Debug logs of my code in ExecuteAnonymous method of tooling API are not available

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I am trying to get the debug logs of my code that I use in the ExecuteAnonymous method of the tooling API. But I am getting a null value. I have added my code below.

```
toolingSoapSforceCom.ExecuteAnonymousResult objExecuteAnonymousResult = new toolingSoapSforceCom.ExecuteAnonymousResult();
toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService objtoolingSoap = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService();
toolingSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element objSessionHeader_element = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
objSessionHeader_element.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
objtoolingSoap.SessionHeader = objSessionHeader_element;

toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo apexLogInfo = new toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo();
apexLogInfo.category='All';
apexLogInfo.level='FINEST';
List< toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo> lstLogInfo = new List< toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo>();
lstLogInfo.add(apexLogInfo);

toolingSoapSforceCom.DebuggingHeader_element objDebuggingHeaderElement = new toolingSoapSforceCom.DebuggingHeader_element();
objDebuggingHeaderElement.debugLevel = 'DEBUGONLY';
objDebuggingHeaderElement.categories = lstLogInfo;

objtoolingSoap.DebuggingHeader = objDebuggingHeaderElement ;
objExecuteAnonymousResult = objtoolingSoap.ExecuteAnonymous(system.debug('*********Hello World**************'););
system.debug('----------------objtoolingSoap.DebuggingInfo---------------->'+ objtoolingSoap.DebuggingInfo  ); 
system.debug('----------------objExecuteAnonymousResult ---------------->'+objExecuteAnonymousResult );
```